# Do I need <ul> with when I have <nav> with <li>?

Tags: html, tags, html-lists, nav

Regarding the `<nav>` HTML5 tag.

What is the difference between this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
  <ul>    
 </nav>
```

and this: (can this work?)

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot put `li` elements outside of a `ul`/`ol`.

But you don't have to use a list at all. You can just put those `a` tags directly under the `nav`:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Photos</a>
</nav>
```

---

For a little more history and a more thorough exploration, read this:

[**Navigation in Lists: To Be or Not To Be**](http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/).

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` is not valid outside of `ul` or `ol` [based on the contexts in which it can be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).  This definition is very strict.

As for `<nav>`, its content model is [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1).  `<li>` is not a flow content element.  In the same vein, `<nav>` does not *have* to contain a list (either `<ul>` or `<ol>`).

My understinding is that navigation lists are better supported by screen readers and better for search engine optimization since search engines won't penalize you for the repetition of the list on pages.  If you avoid the list, they might.  I have absolutely no evidence to back this up -- it's just anecdotal.

Personally, I would go with the simplest valid HTML.  That is just `<nav>` and `<a>` children.